# Returning smallest positive int that does not occur in given list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested-for-loop

Write a function that given an array of A of N int, returns the smallest positive(greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

[image]

I decided to approach this problem by iterating through the list after sorting it.
The value of the current element would be compared to the value of the next element. Because the list is sorted, the list should follow sequentially until the end.
However, if there is a skipped number this indicates the smallest number that does not occur in the list.
And if it follows through until the end, then you should just add one to the value of the last element.

```
def test():
    arr = [23,26,25,24,28]
    arr.sort()
    l = len(arr)

    if arr[-1] <= 0:
        return 1

    for i in range(0,l):
        for j in range(1,l):
            cur_val = arr[i]
            next_val = arr[j]
            num = cur_val + 1
            if num != next_val:
                return num
    if num == next_val:     //if completes the list with no skips
        return arr[j] + 1

print(test())
```

Comment: What value are you expecting from your test?

Comment: for the arr i tested in this case, the output should be 27

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you convert to a set, and you can then efficiently test whether numbers are members of it:

```
def first_int_not_in_list(lst, starting_value=1):
    s = set(lst)
    i = starting_value
    while i in s:
        i += 1
    return i

arr = [23,26,25,24,28]
print(first_int_not_in_list(arr))  # prints 1
```

Comment: shouldnt it print out 27

Comment: The question says the smallest positive integer that doesn't exist in the list, and the answer is 1. If you wanted the behaviour you just said, then you would start with `i=min(s)` and carry on from there. (You would then get rid of the `starting_value` optional argument.) But that is not what the question says.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
def minint(arr):
    s=set(range(min(arr),max(arr)))-set(arr)
    if len(s)>0:
        return min(set(range(min(arr),max(arr)))-set(arr)) #the common case
    elif 1 in arr:
        return max(arr)+1 #arr is a complete range with no blanks
    else:
        return 1 #arr is negative numbers only
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but I ran the code with arr = [23,26,25,24,28] and it outputs 1 instead of 27

Comment: This is the question you are working on:
"Write a function that given an array of A of N int, returns the smallest positive(greater than 0) that does not occur in A." Should the (greater than 0) be (greater than smaller integer in the array)?

Comment: sorry, the question was misunderstood. but yes, after your changes, the result came out correctly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of sets to achieve your goal.

`set.difference()` method is same as relative complement denoted by `A – B`, is the set of all elements in A that are not in B.

Example:

```
Let A = {1, 3, 5} and B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. Then  A - B = {2, 4, 6}.
```

Using `isNeg()` method is used to check whether given set contains any negative integer.

Using `min()` method on `A - B` returns the minimum value from set difference.

Here's the code snippet

```
def retMin(arrList):

   min_val = min(arrList) if isNeg(arrList) else 1
   seqList=list(range((min_val),abs(max(arrList))+2))
   return min(list(set(seqList).difference(arrList))) 

def isNeg(arr):

   return(all (x > 0 for x in arr))
```

Input:

```
print(retMin([1,3,6,4,1,2]))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Input:

```
print(retMin([-2,-6,-7]))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Input:

```
print(retMin([23,25,26,28,30]))
```

Output:

```
24
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code and you should be able to solve your problem:

```
def test():
  arr = [3,-1,23,26,25,24,28]
  min_val = min(val for val in arr if val > 0)
  arr.sort()
  l = len(arr)

  if arr[-1] <= 0:
      return 1

  for i in range(0,l):
    if arr[i] > 0 and arr[i] <= min_val:
      min_val = arr[i] + 1
  return min_val
        
print(test())
```

**EDIT**

It seems you're searching for the the value grater than the minimum positive integer in tha array not sequentially. 
The code it's just the same as before I only change `min_val = 1` to:
`min_val = min(val for val in arr if val > 0)`, so I'm using a lambda expression to get all the positive value of the array and after getting them, using the `min` function, I'll get the minimum of those.
You can [test it here](https://repl.it/repls/NavajowhiteGenuineInstance#main.py) if you want

Comment: why did you initially set min_val to 1

Comment: Because as you asked *the function might returns the smallest positive(greater than 0)*, so I initialize my min_val to the smallest positive greater than 0 that is 1.

Comment: so would i take out my first if statement that checks if the last element is less than zero return 1?

Comment: Yes it's actually useless that if statement because you sort your array so with two for loops as you're trying to solve the problem it's just way more complicated

Comment: No problem. Upvote and mark as your answer if it was helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, I ran the code with  arr = [23,26,25,24,28] and it outputs 1 instead of 27

Comment: I've changed the code, in your question you asked for the *smallest positive(greater than 0) that does not occur in A.*, but I think you want the *smallest positive(**greater than the minimum positive integer in A**) that does not occur in A*. Now you can check with your array and it will return 27.